# Скрипт генерация случайных слов

Tags: javascript

Зайдя на сайт пользователь при нажатии на фразу **Кликните чтобы узнать                 ответ** видит фразы прописанные в JS, скрипт рондомно показывает ниже перечисленные фразы, сколько кликов столько показ фраз. Подскажите пожалуйста как править код, чтобы при заходе на страницу пользователь мог сделать один клик и только один рандомный показ отобразился.

```
html разметка

<div class="ball">
    <div class="panel-text">
        <div class="message">
            Кликните<br>
            чтобы узнать<br>
            ответ
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var i = 0;
            var answers = [
    "НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО<br>МИГАЮЩИЕ КАРТИНКИ",
    "НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО<br>БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ",
    "НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО<br>ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ",
    "НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО<br>ТЕБЕ КАРТИНКИ",
    "НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО<br>УЛЫБКИ КАРТИНКИ",
    "НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО<br>СИЯЮЩИЕ КАРТИНКИ",
            ];

            $(function () {

                $('.panel-text').click(function () {
                    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)
                    showText(this, answers[i]);
                }); ;

                function showText(panel, text) {

                    var panel = $(panel);
                    var msg = $('.message', panel);
                    panel.fadeOut(500, function () {
                        msg.html(text);
                        panel.fadeIn(500);
                    });
                }
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked = false;

window.onclick = (event) => {
    if (clicked == true) {
        return;
    }
    clicked = true;
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)
    showText(this, answers[i]);
}
```

Comment: @СанитариумСделайте пожалуйста правку в ответе. Как будет выглядеть код в полном виде с правкой. Заранее благодарен.